# Counting Cells with Specific Strings Row by Row (IF AND Statement?)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

**Summary**
*Goal*: count cells that contain specific strings in columns A AND B checking each pair of rows in the columns.

- *What I have So Far*: =IF(AND(B3="GA", C3="Grocery"), COUNTIF(C3, "*Grocery*"),0)
- *What I Need*: how to specify continuing this process for each pair of rows in columns A and B.
- *Context*: counting business in different states that have been assigned specific categories. For example, how many businesses in Georgia ("GA") are categorized as "Grocery"?
- [Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dXT_qG_JgBpgzjCK3qPlMqJPw5uCB-7BLRceGRWsio/edit#gid=0)

**Details**

- I am creating a function with the goal of checking cells in columns A and B in the same row  to match a specific string for each, adding +1 to the count if they both match, then checking the next row in columns A and B. How can the function be written to continue checking all of columns A AND B row by row?
  Thank you!

Comment: There is function `BYROW()` to check row by row. Share a sample gs.

Comment: Example Google Sheet added to post and can be found here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dXT_qG_JgBpgzjCK3qPlMqJPw5uCB-7BLRceGRWsio/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try `=BYROW(E16:E25,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(C3:C,x,B3:B,"GA")))` spill array.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(C3:C,E16,B3:B,"GA")` for manually drag down.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! You are a rock star!

Comment: If you found the answer helpful then please accept it (tick mark the answer).

Comment: If you post the comment as an answer I can select it. It cannot be selected as the answer as a comment.

Comment: I have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per sample sheet provided in comment, you can try this formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C,E16,B3:B,"GA")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like-

```
=BYROW(FILTER(B3:C,C3:C<>""),LAMBDA(x,IF(AND(INDEX(x,1,1)="GA",INDEX(x,1,2)="Grocery"),COUNTIFS(C3:C,"Grocery"),"")))
```

Or try-

```
=BYROW(B3:C,LAMBDA(x,IF(AND(INDEX(x,1,1)="GA",INDEX(x,1,1)<>"",INDEX(x,1,2)="Grocery"),COUNTIFS(C3:C,"Grocery",B3:B,"GA",INDEX(ROW(C3:C)),"<="&ROW(x)),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: That is closer to what I am looking for, however it counts all instances of "*Grocery*" and I need to count instances of grocery that are in a specific state, such as GA (column B state and column C category data). Any thoughts on how to do that from here?

Comment: Are you talking about first formula? What would result then 5 instead of 6?

Comment: Try this one `=BYROW(FILTER(B3:C,C3:C<>""),LAMBDA(x,IF(AND(INDEX(x,1,1)="GA",INDEX(x,1,2)="Grocery"),COUNTIFS(C3:C,"Grocery",B3:B,"GA"),"")))`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((B3:B="GA")*(C3:C="Grocery"), 
 COUNTIFS(C3:C, "Grocery", ROW(C3:C), "<="&ROW(C3:C)), 0))
```

Comment: I do not measure performance of new `BYROW()` formula. In case of Excel it is faster than legacy array approach. How about google sheet? Which one is faster? I personally prefer new formulas than older.